# Set or limit maximum volume output

Tags: sound

Is there a way to limit the maximum volume in Ubuntu? Either in the system configs or terminal CLI? Sometimes I'll accidentally press the volume up button on my computer and raise the volume to ear drum breaking levels and I'd like to not accidentally rupture my ear drums

OS: Ubuntu 20.04 64bit

Answer (score 2):

In the **Sound** settings panel, confirm that **Over-Amplification** is disabled... and if you're using external amplified speakers, reduce the physical volume setting there also...

[image]

Comment: Yes it is disabled. However at 80% volume, its still too loud for comfort on my headphones. I wish there was an option on the volume slider to set the maximum volume.

Comment: @quirkworx How about just not turning up the volume that high?

Comment: @heynnema It's unintentional. Every once in awhile my Fn+volume up key combo gets stuck, maxing out the volume and giving me a shock, potentially damaging my hearing and/or speakers. Like OP, I have overamplification disabled but it's still super loud when this happens. It'd be great to have a setting that just says essentially "never go beyond 40% volume" since I never need volumes higher than that anyway, and if I ever do, I can override it.

Comment: @ggorlen Disable the Fn+volume key, or change it to a different keyboard key, or replace the keyboard.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this will help, but if you can't find a better answer, you can always disable your volume keys temporarily using xmodmap.

When I run `xmodmap -pke | grep -i volume` in terminal, I can find the codes for the keys that control volume in my device:

```
keycode 122 = XF86AudioLowerVolume NoSymbol XF86AudioLowerVolume
keycode 123 = XF86AudioRaiseVolume NoSymbol XF86AudioRaiseVolume
```

After that, it's just a matter of setting these keycodes to NoSymbol:

```
xmodmap -e "keycode 122 = NoSymbol"
xmodmap -e "keycode 123 = NoSymbol"
```

This will disable the keys until you turn off your device. To make the change permanent, make it into an executable bash script by saving it as a text file, then running `chmod +x myFileName`, and finally adding it to your "Startup Applications" (this is an app in your version of Ubuntu).

For the record, to re-enable the keys you would need to re-establish the default values of those keys:

```
xmodmap -e "keycode 122 = XF86AudioLowerVolume NoSymbol XF86AudioLowerVolume"
xmodmap -e "keycode 123 = XF86AudioRaiseVolume NoSymbol XF86AudioRaiseVolume"
```

Or, you know, just remove the script from the startup apps (if there is one) and reboot your device.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. But I still like the convenience of raising/lowering the volume using the keys on my laptop