# Prevent hearing damage ubuntu, program

Tags: software-recommendation

After extensively using a Macbook, I eventually transitioned to an Ubuntu laptop. During my time with the Macbook, I installed a program that restricted the maximum volume output when using headphones, ensuring it never exceeded a certain level. This measure was essential to prevent hearing damage. Is there a similar tool available for Ubuntu that can enforce volume limitations and prevent increasing the volume beyond a specified threshold, thus safeguarding against potential auditory harm?

Comment: I use the volume button for that. How should the software know that you have a 1000W amplifier, turned up to 11, connected to your laptop?

Comment: @Jos OP probably wants to limit the maximum sound level *while using headphones*

Comment: Ubuntu remembers the previously set headphone volume (I use Kubuntu, and it does), independently from the speaker volume. So, connect the headphones, and set a low enough volume. Ubuntu should reduce the volume to this lower value when the headphones are connected again. Does that work for you?

Comment: My MacBook use to have an program named Earsafe, that limited the loudness of the sound and also showed info when hearing damage can occur. I am searching for some alternative of that program with an graphical interface

Comment: Related: [Set or limit maximum volume output](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1405632/set-or-limit-maximum-volume-output), but there are no satisfying answers. My "volume up" key combo occasionally gets stuck and maxes out the volume faster than I can take my headphones off, so I also want some way to configure "never output more than 40% volume".

Comment: FWIW, I got Puro Sound Labs volume limited headphones for this reason. If there was a solution to limit the sound in Ubuntu that would have been great, but now at least I have a headphone set that limits the sound to 85db which solves the practical problem for headphones.